# Язык Core GHC.Num.$fNumInteger

Tags: haskell

Что означает `GHC.Num.$fNumInteger` в данном коде?

```
main = 
     print
     @ Integer
     GHC.Show.$fNumInteger
     (+ @ Integer GHC.Num.$fNumInteger 10 11)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ограничения на класс типов (`Num a => ...` в данном случае) в результате компляции превращаются в дополнительный аргумент функции. Этот аргумент представляет собой структуру данных, содержащую реализацию методов класса для данного конкретного типа. Что-то вроде vtable в С++.

Т.е. если у нас есть класс `Foo`

```
class Foo a where
  foo :: a -> String
```

и есть функция, принимающая тип класса `Foo`

```
bar :: Foo a => a -> Int
```

то в Core вызов этой bar для конкретного типа `a` превратится в функцию двух аргументов - словаря `Foo`, содержащего реализацию `foo` для указанного `a` и самого `a`.

В твоем случае ты вызвал `print (10 + 11)`, и в этом выражении числовые константы имеют тип `Num Integer`, а `+` как раз является методом класса `Num`.